# Format iterated records to arrange in a tile format

Tags: html, css, loops, foreach, laravel-blade

I iterated a db record which pulled the records per row, how do I format it to arrange them as tiles, meaning that the second to the first will be arranged by the side, the third will be at the bottom of the first and the fourth at the bottom of the third? The db record will always be 4.

[image: This s what i want to achieve]

[image: This is the way I'm getting it now]

This is the code:

```
@foreach($splitProcedure as $procedureSelected)
                                <TH>{!! $procedureSelected !!}</TH><TH>DESCRIPTION</TH>
                                <TR><TD><div><p>You have used <span class="css-button" id="counter2"></span> words.</p>{!! Form::textarea('productdescription', Input::old('productdescription'), ['class'=>'mid first-input-div', 'placeholder'=>'Please, within 200-250 characters describe what the company is about', 'id'=>'productdescription']) !!}</div></TD><TD></TD></TR>
                                <TR><TD><div>{!! Form::text('productname', Input::old('productname'), ['class'=>'mid first-input-div', 'placeholder'=>'enter company name', 'id'=>'productname']) !!}</div></TD><TD></TD></TR>
                                {!! Form::hidden('hiddenCompanyId', Input::old('selectedCompanyHiddenId'), ['id'=>'selectedCompanyHiddenId']) !!}
                                {!! Form::hidden('hiddenCompanyName', Input::old('selectedCompanyHidden'), ['id'=>'selectedCompanyHidden']) !!}

                                @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a framework like: bootstrap or foundation to achieve this or write your own css to create such tiles and add your data to it. Rather than using html tables, as I think its really difficult or impossible to design it as you can see if you observe that the rows coming from database are directly inserted into   tags so you dont have a predefined table with the format you are looking for.

You can achieve it by creating a table with rows and columns you like and get each row from database and insert and hard-code them to the right place you want(This is a bad way to do because as soon as you add a single more row in database it all breaks).

Or you could do this :

```
<div class="row">
@foreach
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
       //Your data here create a single tile with product name, company id, etc
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

And the foreach loop will insert each rows data into each tile. But you need a framework or css skills to get you the right results.